# Google play services error firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am new to firebase and flutter. I was watching a video and I decided to make a reminder app using flutter and firebase, but as soon as I connect the database, the following ***error comes***.

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27206): com.learnflutter.firebasee requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(27206): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore(27206): (23.0.4) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
W/utter.firebase(27206): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
W/utter.firebase(27206): Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206): FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-okhttp-0
E/AndroidRuntime(27206): Process: com.learnflutter.firebasee, PID: 27206
E/AndroidRuntime(27206): java.lang.AssertionError: Method getAlpnSelectedProtocol not supported for object SSL socket over Socket[address=firestore.googleapis.com/142.250.77.42,port=443,localPort=52872]
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.OptionalMethod.invoke(OptionalMethod.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.okhttp.internal.OptionalMethod.invokeWithoutCheckedException(OptionalMethod.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.getSelectedProtocol(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:571)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
I/Process (27206): Sending signal. PID: 27206 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

The following is my pubspec yaml and my build gradle file:

***Build Gradle:***

```
ef localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.learnflutter.firebasee"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'



}
```

***Pubspec Yaml:***

```
name: firebasee
description: A new Flutter project.


environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  #Firebase
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  add_2_calendar: ^2.1.2
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Can someone please help me out? I have been googling the error and trying different things but nothing solves the problem ://

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Google Play (CH Play) on your simulator or use a real device instead because the service you used in your app requires Google Play to process.